# Python import service_identity error: cannot import name DNSName

Tags: python, scrapy

I start learning Scrapy and got this error message. I have googled it and installed/upgraded service_identity and related python packages but still received the same error when importing service_identity.

- OS: Windows 7 64-bit
- Python: 2.7.15 Anaconda
- service_identity: 18.1.0
- pyopenssl: 17.5.0
- pyasn1: 0.4.5
- pyasn1-modules: 0.2.3

Error msg:

```
import service_identity
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "ipython-input-2-709fa376dd62", line 1, in <module>
    import service_identity

  File "C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\service_identity\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from . import cryptography, pyopenssl

  File "C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\service_identity\cryptography.py", line 9, in <module>
    from cryptography.x509 import (

ImportError: cannot import name DNSName
```

Comment: Please, provide the error message as text to make it easy for other people in your situation to find it.

Comment: If you followed the [official installation instructions](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html), consider [opening a bug report](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/issues)